# Confusion in Bjt Bias stabilization

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, analog, dc, bjt

Which of the following main properties of a bipolar junction transistor make it necessary for the transistor to have bias stabilization?

1. Variation of VBE with temperature
2. Variation of h with temperature
3. Variation of Ico with temperature
4. Variation of h with transistor replacement
5. Variation of VBE with transistors replacement
6. Variation of Ico with transistor replacement.

This is a previous year competitive exam question in which option was

(a)1,2 and 6

(B)1,3 and 4

(C)2,3 and 5

(D)3,4,5 and 6

The answer given by them is option B that is 1,3,4.

But my answer was all parameters are interrelated so it

**Ico**
The flow of current in the circuit produces heat at the junctions. This heat increases the temperature at the junctions.
Since the minority carriers are temperature-dependent ( gets doubled for energy 10C raise in temperature), they increase with the temperature.
This in turn increases the and hence Q – point gets shifted.

**Vbe**
Vbe changes with temperature at the rate of 2.5mv/c so the Stabilization point also changes.

**h or Beta**
Beta value also depends on temperature value and now two-transistor have the same Beta Value.

this many things I know, so the first 4 option is correct. The last 2 options don't know how related  helps me regarding these things any effect on Vbe/Ico if transistor changes

Comment: Why downvote if some problem plz tell in comment.

Comment: I didn't downvote but your question may seem too broad to few ppl.  A better way to ask is to be more specific. Break it down into few small questions. Post one small question at a time. Like, ask why hfe changes with temperature or transistor replacement..

Comment: Because a reply simply requires a "yes" or "no" I see no problem to give a short answwer: Stabilization of Ic against some parameter variation resp. uncertainty is absolutely necessary because of (1) and (with reduced significance) because of (2) and (4). The problem of (1) is given with the tempco d(Vbe)/d(T)=-2mV/K for Ic=const.. That means we have to reduce Vbe by 2mV/degree when we want to compensate the Ic increase with temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exam question is badly formed. *All* those variations can have some effect -- some (probably) more significant than others -- and that significance can depend on the biasing arrangement itself.

Clearly VBE varies with temperature and can be expected.

h (hFE; ~beta) also varies with temperature (and bias current selected)

Ico and VBE are quite directly related (also with beta slightly) -- so it varies. However most circuits don't directly deal with Ico, rather VBE.

The other questions are to do with replacement devices. this depends strongly on if replacements are from the same or a different manufacturer. beta is a commonly described spec and variation among transistors. VBE (and Ico) are not usually specified (usefully), but will vary significantly among different manufacturers. For the same manufacturer, VBE will only have small variations (perhaps 20 mV -- too much for a current mirror, but OK for a discrete circuit).

Comment: I think the "VBE variation" deserves some explanation: We have d(Vbe)/d(T)=-2mV/K. That means: For a temperature increase of 1 deg - and for CONSTANT Ic - we must externally reduce the Vbe by 2mV.

Answer (score 1):

To know what are the changes to "Quiet Point",
search only the equation of the QP (complete equation) ... :-)
then calculate the differential of all variables with respect to the temperature ... for a single transistor.
All the variables of interest will appear, but one has to know how these are varying with temperature.

This could be a "little" complicated, so "simulating" is easier.

See AppCAD from Avago Technologies  http://www.hp.woodshot.com/

Here a Maple sheet "example", I did, when I was a little younger ...

1
[image]
2
[image]
3
[image]
4
[image]

For those who have some interest in this, here is a simulation of curves "beta" versus Ic,
parameters Vcc (5,15,25,35 V) and Temperature (0,25,50,75 °C).

[image]

Comment: (-15) wow ? but why ???